# document.write doesnt print anything to the page

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
            function myFunc() {
            var doc = parent.frames[1].document;
            doc.open();
            doc.write(<html><body class="dialogBody"><form><table width="100%"><tr class="colHeader" width="100%"><td align=left valign=middle>&nbsp;</td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Cell2</td></tr><tr class=normalRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name='select' value=0/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed</td></tr><tr class=altRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name='select' value=1/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed2</td></tr></table></form></body></html>);
            doc.close();
            }
            var topFrame = "<a href='#' " +"onClick='parent.myFunc()'>Click me</a>";
            var botFrame = ""; 
            myFunc(); 
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="50%,*">
    <frame src="javascript:parent.topFrame"><input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="myFunc()" /></frame>
    <frame src="javascript:parent.botFrame">
    </frameset>

</html>
```

This code when loaded using Safari or firefox shows blank. Can you guess why?

Comment: The language attribute has been deprecated for years, type is required. Also, get rid of the HTML comment delimiters inside the script element, they serve no practical purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in quotes and should work:

```
 doc.write('<html><body class="dialogBody"><form><table width="100%"><tr class="colHeader" width="100%"><td align=left valign=middle>&nbsp;</td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Cell2</td></tr><tr class=normalRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name=\'select\' value=0/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed</td></tr><tr class=altRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name=\'select\' value=1/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed2</td></tr></table></form></body></html>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML on

```
doc.write(<html><body class="dialogBody"><form><table width="100%"><tr class="colHeader" width="100%"><td align=left valign=middle>&nbsp;</td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Cell2</td></tr><tr class=normalRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name='select' value=0/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed</td></tr><tr class=altRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name='select' value=1/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed2</td></tr></table></form></body></html>);
```

is not a string. The quotes inside the string will need to be escaped. It will end up looking like this:

```
doc.write("<html><body class=\"dialogBody\"><form><table width=\"100%\"><tr class=\"colHeader\" width="100%"><td align=left valign=middle>&nbsp;</td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Cell2</td></tr><tr class=normalRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name='select' value=0/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed</td></tr><tr class=altRow><td width=20 height=20px align=left valign=middle><input type=radio height=12px width=12px align =center vlign=middle name='select' value=1/></td><td height=20px align=left valign=middle>Ed2</td></tr></table></form></body></html>");
```

Comment: even if I use "" around the above html I still do not get anything

Comment: Because you are using multiple quote types. Escape the quotes.

Comment: Yes, each time within the code that double quotes appear, precede them with a slash \, otherwise JavaScript "thinks" the string of code has finished.

Comment: @David - Depends on what type of quote you use as the outer quote. If it's `'` then you must escape the single quotes.

Comment: It's not even valid English, @Blender.

Comment: @Jeff - You should edit your answer with the info from the comments and show the solution. You were definitely on the right track. Your answer is just missing a few more key details.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: It may need some formatting changes (a bit late for that) but it was getting at the right idea.